# C# Add buttons with images and handlers

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a simple problem, but since it's the first time I'm using C#/XAML here I go.

The XAML file contains a StackPanel to which I want to add clickable images at runtime.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="grid_" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10 0 10 0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
</StackPanel>
```

I didn't succeed in creating a *click event* on those images, and I've read I could try with buttons, changing their background. This is my code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            Button j = new Button();


            //Image j = new Image();
            //j.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/my_thumb.png", UriKind.Relative));

            var brush = new ImageBrush();
            j.BackgroundImage = brush;

            //j.MouseDown += new RoutedEventHandler(this.changeImage);
            grid_.Children.Add(j);
            Grid.SetRow(j, i);    
        }
```

Now, how can I change the button image, and add a handler to retrieve which button has been clicked? The error I'm getting is

```
Error   3   'System.Windows.Controls.Button' does not contain a definition for 'BackgroundImage' and no extension method 'BackgroundImage' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Button' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

You can see from my comments in the code that I am still retaining the plain image approach, just to be sure: in case you know how to make my images clickable, please tell me :)

I can settle down for an event handler that could just retrieve the button image source file name, in case.

Can you point me in the right direction? Remember I am a complete newbie! :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `Click` event

```
j.Click += new EventHandler(onButtonClick);
```

And then in the event handler

```
void onButtonClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var clickedButton = sender as Button;
    // do your stuff..    
}
```

Comment: Why fo I have this error? Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler' to 'System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler'. My code is: "j.Click += new EventHandler(this.changeImage);" and my handler is "public void changeImage(Object sender, EventArgs e)"?

Comment: It should be "public void changeImage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)" && "new RoutedEventHandler(this.changeImage)"

Comment: Change eventhandler to routedeventhandler

Comment: Awesome! Any hint on the background image? I have that BackgroundImage cannot be used (see my edit) with Buttons.

Comment: My fault, I didn't include System.Drawing, System.Drawing.Imaging, you solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

XAML

```
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="400,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.258,-5" Click="Button_Click" Height="80" Width="80"/>
```

C#

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Background = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:/Images/timerg.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) };

    }
```

or C#

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
            Uri u = new Uri("ms-appx:/Images/timer.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            bmp.UriSource = u;
            // NOTE: change starts here
            Image i = new Image();
            i.Source = bmp;
            button1.Content = i;
    }
```